# In kubernetes, localhost_access_log.txt is output to file in the pod。 How do I to collect them using filebeat?

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, filebeat, access-log

In kubernetes, tomcat catalina.log is collected to stdout，but localhost_access_log.txt is output to file in the pod。 How do I to collect access log by kubernetes log driver？I am currently using filebeat

Answer (score 1):

Deploy filebeat as a sidecar with tomcat and create a volume mount shared by both the tomcat and filebeat container. The filebeat container can read the log files created by tomcat container from the shared volume mount.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: filebeat-sidecar
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.5.0
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/logs
        - name: filebeat-config
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
          subPath: filebeat.yml
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/logs
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
      - name: logs-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: filebeat-config
        configMap:
          name: filebeat-sidecar-config
          items:
            - key: filebeat.yml
              path: filebeat.yml
```

https://capstonec.com/2019/12/16/getting-tomcat-logs-from-kubernetes-pods/